# Как настроить config vars при деплоинге python бота на heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot, heroku

в туториалах heroku написано, что конфигурационные переменные типа токена бота надо забить командой `heroku config:set TOKEN=...`, что я и сделал, а использовать их с помощью библиотеки **boto**, что я так же повторил, но после запуска бот сразу же останавливается.
попытка использования переменной TOKEN:

```
    from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
    token = S3Connection(os.environ['TOKEN'])
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
```

вывод heroku logs показал это:
[image: вывод <code>heroku logs</code>]

Comment: А почему у Вас там token бота вместо S3_Key и S3_Secret? Команда token = S3Connection(os.environ['TOKEN']) подключает вас к хосту на S3, а не к API бота. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: ааа, а видимо я все не так понял, а как в таком случае использовать TOKEN?

Comment: Ну вероятно вам нужно создать бакет и положить в него ваш скрипт с ботом, внутри которого использовать токен бота согласно документации той библиотеки, которую вы будете использовать для работы с ботом.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
import os
token = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
```